# Ion Exchange chromatography

Tags: analytical-chemistry, chromatography

[image]

Suppose that Anion exchanger is used in the stationary phase
normally -ve charge A.A will be eluted first as it will not attach
but my question is does the zwitter ion(have net charge 0 will be the same as -ve charge A.A?
or it will take a longer time than -ve charge A.A?

Comment: It depends on the charge distribution on the surface of the protein, and usually the best way to tackle this is to do experiments with different pH values. There are too many parameter (charge distribution, pH stability, interaction with other proteins) to get more than a conceptual overview. Everything else is empirical.